# Pass html form action parameters to django view

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm making an app to save mileage of a truck per state. I've already passed required data to my view, and then I thought to change my urls to more logical. And after that I faced a problem.
I don't know what should be instead of "unit.unit_number", and it is required, in my html file for it to work correctly. I didn't find anything that could explain how to deal with it.

If I try to access mywebsite.com/core/units/1/locations/add/ I get next error message: 
"NoReverseMatch at /core/units/1/locations/add/"

But if I put just a number (1 for example) instead of "unit.unit_number" it loads the page normally, but I get an error after trying to post the data:
"TypeError at /core/units/1/locations/add/
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be an iterable, not int"

```html
<form action="{% url 'Core:unit_add_location' unit.unit_number %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container border-full">

      <button type="button" class="button button-normal" onclick="AddRow()">Add</button>
      <input type="submit" class="button button-submit" name="count-ifta" value="Save">

      <div class="inner-container border-top-bottom">
        <table id="myTable" name="state-miles-data">
          <thead>
            <th class="text-blue">State</th>
            <th class="text-blue">Miles</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
        <br>
      </div>

    </form>

    <button type="button" class="button button-normal" onclick="AddRow()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```py
def unit_data(request, unit_number):
    return HttpResponse(unit_number)

def unit_add_location(request, unit_number):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'Core/add_location.html')

    elif "POST" == request.method:

        states_request = request.POST.getlist('states')
        miles_request = request.POST.getlist('miles')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Core:unit_data', args=(unit_number)))
```

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('units/', views.units_all, name = 'units_all'),
    path('units/<int:unit_number>/', views.unit_data, name = 'unit'),
    path('units/<int:unit_number>/locations/', views.unit_locations, name = 'unit_locations'),

    path('units/<int:unit_number>/locations/add/', views.unit_add_location, name = 'unit_add_location'),
    path('units/<int:unit_number>/locations/<int:report_id>', views.unit_location, name = 'unit_location'),
]
```

So the thing I want to make is post the data and redirect to url "mywebsite.com/units/1/locations/" that is processed by the view "unit_locations"

Comment: To what resolves the url the form calls to when using unit.unit_number? I mean is unit in the templatecontext?

Comment: Where is unit_number supposed to be coming from?

Comment: unit is a model with field unit_number, it should've been passed with get request

Comment: Show the full urls.py

Answer (score 1):

To the second part about the iterable: (reverse('Core:unit_data', args=(unit_number))) <<< you want (unit_number,) which is a tuple not an int. Spot the , it is important.

Comment: Yep, just did it. It helped, but still I couldn't make a redirect to another view, must use the same one.
Also the problem was in get request. Needed to pass parameters next way:
" if "GET" == request.method:
        unit = get_object_or_404(Unit, unit_number=unit_number)
 return render(request, 'Core/add_location.html', {"unit" : unit})"